# Save row value from grid view to database for each ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my gridview I have 2 column, a boundfield academy name and a template field dropdown list choice.
I want when click on submit the choice that have been made through the dropdown list is saved in the database together with the Id of the academy.The Id academy is the data key name of the gridview.

Here is the table where the data should save:

tblAcademy

```
acad_Id acad_Name
   1      `a`
   2       b
   3       c
   4       d
   5       e
```

tblAcademySelection

```
acad_id stud_id  order_of_preference
1        2         1
3        2         3
5        2         4
1        6         1
```

The stud_id will be obtain by the session id of the connected student.

Here is my grid view code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gdvAcadSelec" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="acad_Id" DataSourceID="srcAcademy"
      OnRowDataBound="gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound"
    CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
    EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_name"
            HeaderText="Academy" SortExpression="acad_name" />

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choice">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPref" runat="server">
                          
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="srcAcademy"
    TypeName="dataAccessLayer"
    SelectMethod="getAcademy"
    runat="server" />
```

Grid view code behind:

```
   protected void gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Find the DropDownList in the Row
            DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlPref") as DropDownList);
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("1"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("2"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("3"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem("4"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem("5"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem("6"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem("7"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem("8"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem("9"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem("10"));
        }
    }

    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvAcadSelec.Rows)
        {
            string someVariableName = row.Cells[0].Text;
            
        }
    }
```

Till now I have only for each to loop in each row but I am stuck on how to save from the grid view to my database.
Any help will by appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is not hard. The trick is to persist the data - that makes this whole setup quite easy.

And of course our table does have a Primary key column - right????

So, assuming this Grid markup:

```
   <div style="padding:25px">
        <br />
        
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table" 
            Width="25%"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_id" HeaderText="acad_id"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="stud_id" HeaderText="stud_id"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboOrder" runat="server"
                            DataTextField = "Text"
                            DataValueField ="Value">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdSave_Click"/>
    </div>
```

Ok, now our code to fill this grid is this:

```
    List<ListItem> MyOrderList;
    DataTable rstData;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
            ViewState["rstData"] = rstData;
        }
        else
            rstData = (DataTable)ViewState["rstData"];
    }


    void LoadGrid()
    {
        MyOrderList = new List<ListItem>();
        MyOrderList.Add(new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            MyOrderList.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));

        rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL =
                "SELECT * FROM tblAcademySelection ORDER BY order_of_Preference";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, so now we have this:

[image]

The code for setting up the combo box is of course on row data bound

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            DropDownList cboOrder = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboOrder");
            cboOrder.DataSource = MyOrderList;
            cboOrder.DataBind();
            // now set cbo to current choice.

            if (gData["order_of_Preference"] == null)
                cboOrder.SelectedItem.Value = "0";
            else
                cboOrder.SelectedValue = gData["order_of_Preference"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

So, now all we are missing is the "save" changes button. Note that this save button could save "many" columns from the GV, but we only have one this example.

So, the code for the save all edits button would be this:

```
   protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // send any grid edits back to table
        // this could be several columns we want to save

        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rstData.Rows[gRow.DataItemIndex];
            DropDownList cboOrder = (DropDownList)gRow.FindControl("cboOrder");
            OneRow["order_of_Preference"] = cboOrder.SelectedItem.Value;
        }

        // ok, table has any and all edits. Now send table back to database.
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAcademySelection";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);

                // now refresh grid to show update
                LoadGrid();
            }
        }
    }
```

so the above sends changes back to our table. And then in one database operation, sends any table changes back to the database.

## Edit: How to approach this?

Ok, with a better explain, the problem is clear.

We have a nice grid, but ALSO want to add/attach a child table that allows user defined sort of the table. This is reasonable.

So, lets start out with some sample data. Say we have a table of bookings.

Might look like this:

[image]

Now, of course the above is going to make a VERY ugly grid and ui.

And we also assume that child "ordering table" which we will attached to the above.

So, lets fire up the query builder, join up the tables for a NICE looking grid.

Our view (we save it), looks like this now:

[image]

So, in above, we have that "order table". Note how we join on the two columns used in that order table. And of course, we use LEFT joins - right?
(ask why this is so if you don't know).

NOTE SUPER close - I do include both the PK row and Ordery by in that child "order table" we need the PK row id for this table to allow ease of saving data.

So, so now we have a nice query, one that joins in the data.

So, all we do now is feed our GV the above query.

We ALSO of course have to deal with the child table of order by. To save BOATLOADS of complex code?
If the child records don't exist, we just add them FIRST. Then you are free to set your order choices, and our code thus ONLY has to save choices - not figure out to add them at the same time.

So, here is our grid now:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table" 
            Width="45%"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FromDate" HeaderText="From"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ToDate" HeaderText="To"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboOrder" runat="server"
                            DataTextField = "Text"
                            DataValueField ="Value" 
                            OnTextChanged="cboOrder_TextChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And now our code to load the gridview is this:

```
   List<ListItem> MyOrderList;
    DataTable rstData;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
        else
            rstData = (DataTable)ViewState["rstData"];
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM VBook ORDER BY MyOrder");

        DataTable rstOrder = MyRst("SELECT * from tblBookOrder WHERE ID = 0");
        // check or add child rows to order by table
        foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
        {
            if ( OneRow.IsNull("MyOrder"))
            {
                // add child row
                DataRow MyNewRow = rstOrder.NewRow();
                MyNewRow["Hotel_ID"] = OneRow["Hotel_ID"];
                MyNewRow["People_ID"] = OneRow["People_ID"];
                MyNewRow["MyOrder"] = rstOrder.Rows.Count + 1;
                rstOrder.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
            }
        }
        if (rstOrder.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MyRstUpdate(rstOrder,"tblBookOrder");  // save order table
            // we just added child order records, so re-load our table
            rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM Vbook ORDER BY MyOrder");
        }

        ViewState["rstData"] = rstData;
        MakeOList();
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

So above code ALSO creates the reocrds for the drop down - and we ONLY create as many records as exiting. And we ONLY then create allowed drop down choices for JUST those choices (saves BOATLOADS of code to deal with choosing values that don't make sense).

We also thus fix the issue if a user say tries to move say 4 to 1. We allow this, and simple re-number the choices. Again, HUGE boatload of saving here - (else trying to remove choices in each dropdown - way too much work).

Ok, so after above code runs, we now have a human readable grid like this:

[image]

So, far, not a lot of code, and we have a human readable grid.

Now, we need to let the user choose from the drop down. As per above code, they ONLY have the choices there. So, if I want to move first row to 3, then I do this:

[image]

Logic:

Well, move all lower rows DOWN by one, and then set this row to value of order by 3.

The code not hard and very little code - but certinly carefull code.

We set autopost back for the combo, and thus we have this code for the  combo box:

so we will simple RE-NUMBER the choices. Again, saves a boatload of UI issues in regards to picking the same values.

So, this code looks to work:

```
    protected void cboOrder_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cbo = (DropDownList)sender;
        int MoveStart = Convert.ToInt32(cbo.SelectedValue) - 1;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cbo.NamingContainer;
        int MoveEnd = gRow.DataItemIndex;

        int MoveDirection = -1;
        if (MoveStart > MoveEnd)
        {
            MoveDirection = 1;
            MoveEnd = MoveStart;
            MoveStart = gRow.DataItemIndex;
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow gR in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (gR.DataItemIndex >= MoveStart & gR.DataItemIndex <= MoveEnd)
            {
                DataRow dr = rstData.Rows[gR.DataItemIndex];
                rstData.Rows[gR.DataItemIndex]["MyOrder"]
                    = ((int)rstData.Rows[gR.DataItemIndex]["MyOrder"]) - MoveDirection;
            }
        }
        rstData.Rows[gRow.DataItemIndex]["MyOrder"] = cbo.SelectedValue;            
        SaveGrid();  // upate/save the child table order to database
        // re-load grid
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

We simple loop the data - and if the bump up or bump down row is between our start/end value - we update.

So, after above choice (3), we now have this:

[image]

So, the left joins is quite a nice trick/idea here. It pulls in the people name, the hotel name, and we use that saved view to ALSO PULL in the order by child table we have.

Now, Rossetta stone trick here:

We after changing the values in that data set have to update ONLY the child table. And we can do this EVEN based on that one mutli-table join!!!

This is the first time in public I have shared this trick.

Here is the save code used in above event stub:

```
    void SaveGrid()
    {
        // ok, table has any and all edits. Now send table back to database.
        // but we ONLY take the two columns from that multi-join table for 
        // this update.
        // BIG BIG surprise!!! = we do NOT have to update back to database 
        // based on the source table!!! - we can update to the other table!!!!

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID AS OID, MyOrder FROM tblBookOrder", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is that cool or what? i used the grid data source (rstData). But to update all changes, I used sql against the child table. This thus explains why I included the PK row value in that GV query. It allowed me to update that child table without a boatload of code, or even having to write code to pull out all the values from the GV ad having to cook up a complex row by row update bit of code.

The other few routines are:

Build the cbo box choices - we only crank out number of choices based on number of rows. But then this works for 4 rows, or 15 - it don't matter!!!

```
    void MakeOList()
    {
        MyOrderList = new List<ListItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= rstData.Rows.Count; i++)
            MyOrderList.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));

    }
```

Our gridview data row bound event (to set combo box), is much like before

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            DropDownList cboOrder = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboOrder");
            cboOrder.DataSource = MyOrderList;
            cboOrder.DataBind();
            // now set cbo to current choice.
            cboOrder.SelectedValue = gData["MyOrder"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

So, this can be done - not a lot of code either.

and MyRst?

that returns a datable.

So these two helper routines:

```
    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rst;
    }

    void MyRstUpdate(DataTable rst,string sTable)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sTable, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rst);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note it is VERY critical that in the multi-table join, we include the PK id of that that child table.
Since we have two "ID" as pk, then I gave that child table ID an alias of OID.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. When you are selecting * in the loadgrid() function are you assuming that the column order by preference already have data? As if it is the first a student submit this form, there will be no record for order of preference.

Comment: Well, do you mean no data by no values in that column, or do you mean no data by not having rows of data? (big difference). If the order pref column has no values, then no problem. If you suggesting that no rows exist, then we have a different stated problem, and would have to take this new information into account for this problem. In other words you are now hinting that the posted row data example does not have rows then? So no values set in order pref column - no problem.  but no rows existing as of yet - MUCH different issue, but certainly something that can be dealt with.

Comment: I would suggest that your query that fills the grid is VAST different then what you posted. That grid query no doubt would join in + display the actual text values for the GV. So I would run that query into a datatable, process each row to add the child reocrds into the order table. Then re-query, and bind that query to the grid. That way you don't have to inter-mix code to add the child rows vs editing existing child rows in that table. So the final update code will not really use the grid data source, but update the child table. So, I would just before grid load add all child records first.

Comment: It is no row exist because it is a filling form, the records of which academy a student  choose and in what order of preference should be stored. The one that I posted is just an illustration of how my tblAcademy selection should look like. Is there a big problem with that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I mention in my post the stud_Id is obtain via session ID.As only student will able to access this page when they are log.

Comment: Ok, see my edit as to how you can do this and approach this.

Comment: That's a superb code, specially the one where we only update the child table. Thank you very much. Is the MyRst a function " rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM VBook ORDER BY MyOrder");" ? The code that you provide me give the order of preference of those who are already done. In my case a student need to have his own academy selection and order of preference. When the student will fill first academy selection there will be acad_id and his stud_id store in the database. This will be store when the student no submit the selection and of course with the order of preference for each academy he choice

Comment: The order of preference selection should not be same. This is why I want when the student choose his first academy in the dropdown list, it should start by 1 and the other number should be disable or hide, the 2 must be enable for his second selection,  it should increase to next dropdown each time a selection is made. I don't know if it is possible. Do you think it is?

Comment: Sure, but the code takes the current record order, and sets up say for 5 records their combo boxes pre-filled with the values. So on the fly I insert + create the child records in the order table first time only. So they will see say the 5 records in their order that they were - so what if the combo boxes are now pre filled. The are free now to choose + set any order they want. When we start, no child order records exist - but I check for them missing and add them with a default number at 1, 2 etc. This eliminates the need for "please" choose - but they are still free to choose order.

Comment: I don't see how a problem exists of displaying 5 records with the comb boxes filled or not. They still see 5 records in some default order. How is that a problem? How does this change anything? They will see 5 records and are free to order them. I mean, the 5 records will display with, or without the cbo box chosen, so why a problem if we pre-fill them in the order that they would have seen in the first place??? Why not pre-fill the 5 choices in the current order that they would see or get anyway???

Comment: With that setup, you NEVER will get two numbers with the same value. If you change say 1 to 4, then what supposed to occur? Well then 1 gets moved to position 4 and all 3 previous move down by one. I can't really see how else this would work? Why allow say with 5 records, you want 9 or 8 as a choice????

Comment: Sure. pre-fill the list is not a problem for me. What I want to avoid is the selection of same order of preference for the academy. For eg, a student cannot have a order of preference of 1 for more than one academy. Each order of preference is unique for an academy in the selection

Comment: Oh ok,now i understand.Yes it should max of 10 selection

Comment: One last thing, how come is there no insert and update statement.How is the data is suppose to insert in the table?

Comment: And they can't. if you say want to move #4 to #1 postion? then they are all bumped down by one, and there only one #1 allowed. I mean, I can't see much else how you can do this. We never allow the user to have the same number, since when you move or choose say 1-4, then the others are bumb up or down. So you can never have two the same. I mean, if you have #1, and wanted to change that or made a mistake, what do you want to do?

Comment: Yes,that right,thanks for this clarification

Comment: We do have insert statements - we used "add row". Once those 4 child records are added, then we only ever have to udpate them. So we did not use sql insert, but used a data table and add row. And for updating, we did  not use sql updates, but use the data table .update() method. You could try and write all those sql update statements, but that is a boatload of work - VERY much why we used a data table here in place of sql updates. We don't have to actually save during cbo selection. We could move things around and then have one save button - but again, that one data update will update all rows

Comment: We re-number the numbers.  Then yes, we re-update the child order table. But as noted, we are able to do that with ONE table.Update command. This is MUCH less work then trying to loop and execute a update command when we bump the numbers up, or down. By limiting the choices as we done, we save a BLOAT load of user issues, and then can't mess this up.  As noted, we could just change the table, re-display and have one save or un-do button. But for this example, I do save the data when you select/change the cbo box. We could let user change/play and then have save button.

Comment: Ok,that new to me thanks for that, And for the MyRst function, I do not see it.

Comment: ok, I added that to the end - thought I had posted - but I have now.

Comment: I have found that the "please select 0" must be in. This because a student is not forcefully to choose all the 10 academy, The min is 1 and the max is 10

Comment: I think you miss a the vbook table in th rstData. In my case I think the rsData is the fetching of student in tblStudent and rstOrder is the tblAcademySelection ? In rstOrder ,the where condition should be replace by the session student ID

Comment: Don't grasp the 1-10 issue? If you only have 6 records to display, then you only have 6 things to order? If there are 4 or 15 records, it should not matter? If the grid only has say 7 choices to set sort order, then why would I offer 10 choices to order only 7 records? Now you note only a max of 10 choices. But if only 4 records are to be display for "order" to be set, then why would we want to offer more then 4 choices to set that order??? And if we did in the future have 15 records, then the code would work.  Perhaps the 1-10 has specials meaning? Don't we just care about setting the order?

Comment: Yes, I only posted VBOOK graphic design. I mean, we don't want to display student_id, but his nice name etc., right? I can post the VBOOK view/query. As noted, surely we not going to display a grid with those "id" numbers - the user will be confused.

Comment: Are we just setting the sort order for display/user? if choices are an academy, then the drop down would and should display the Academy as nice text and we set acadmany_ID. If solution is to select academy, then we don't care about 1-10, but only a drop own that shows the nice text academy name, and we store/set Acadmeny_ID. If this is the case, then order column would be in academy table, and we don't save it.  No different then display name from that table - we don't save it again - we sql join for that information. This is starting to look like the OrderBy belongs in academy table.

Comment: >>n rstOrder ,the where condition should be replace by the session student ID (yes - and that is good, since it means we are to show/display ONE student here - your posted data showed different student_id's - and that was a mountain of confusing here.  It makes perfect sense that the grid will only show one student with their preference for a given academy. So, this does look good and ok now.

Comment: No we are not display/user just the selection of academy. But I getting confuse of what statement should be put the rstData. On my side I put rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblAcademy_Selection"); and   DataTable rstOrder = MyRst("SELECT * from tblAcademy_Selection where stud_Id=4");.  These are both giving me all the selection in the tblAcademy_Selection and not just for the login student.